# Run-time error 80004005 Invalid argument ADODB SharePoint list using VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint, adodb

Hello I have code like below and when I run it i got error in line marked below. Error is "Run-time error 80004005 Invalid argument". I was looking for some tips to solve the problem but none of them helps me. Thanks for any advice.

```
Sub TestInsertToSharepoint()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn As String
Dim sSQL As String



sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID = "guid"
sSHAREPOINT_SITE = "sharepointsite"


sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With cn
.ConnectionString = sConn
.Open <--------- here I got error
End With

sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblAddingData (Title) VALUES ('FIRSTEDIT')"

rs.Open sSQL, cn



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issues. There are two ways to solve the issue:

1. Save the Excel file in One Drive and connection string would stop throwing error. Strangely it doesn't run from local folder but runs from OneDrive folder.
2. Run it from Excel 2013.

Please let me know if it helps.